# how to use xpointer to link to specific node from another document

Tags: xml, xpointer

I have two xml files. and I want to refer the value of a node from the other xml file.

example: 1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

an 2.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<doc xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude">
<xi:include href="1.xml" xpointer="bk101"/>
</doc>
```

When I execute 2.xml, I get a error saying 
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<doc><xi:include href="book.xml" xpointer="bk101"/></doc>
```

Can I get some help in resolving the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a dummy stylesheet to resolve the error:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="http://www.w3.org/StyleSheets/TR/W3C-REC.css"?>
```

Use a DTD to declare the ID attributes of the `book` elements as type ID:

```
<!ATTLIST book id ID #IMPLIED>
```

Save it as something like `ids.dtd`, then use a doctype in `1.xml` to reference it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE id-list SYSTEM "ids.dtd">
```

**References**

- [xml:id Version 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/)
- [XInclude:Fragment Example](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#fragment-example)
- [Associating Style Sheets with XML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/)